# Check for existence of a value in a dynamic table in java play?

Tags: java, scala, selenium, playframework

In my IntegrationTest.java class, I have the following test

```
   @Test
       public void testTableIsPopulated() {
           running(testServer(3333, fakeApplication(inMemoryDatabase())), HTMLUNIT, browser -> {
               browser.goTo("http://localhost:9000");
               assertThat(browser.pageSource(), hasKey("key")));
           });
       }
```

Which fails to ascertain whether the dynamic table produced in

/views/index.scala.html contains id=key.
This effectively tests whether the table is populated with values as the table is populated using the javascript

```
   .each(data, function(key, value) {
```

So no key implies no value.

What should replace the `assertThat` line that will ascertain if the key exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
       browser.goTo("http://localhost:3333");
```

The problem wasn't `assertThat()`, I sent the request to the wrong port.